# PHP file outside doc root needs files outside and inside the document root

Tags: php

I have a library of classes, all interrelated.

Some files are inside the document root and some are outside using the `<Directory> and Alias` features in httpd.conf

Assuming I have 3 files:

```
webroot.php (Inside the document root)
alias_directory.php (Inside a folder outside the doc root)
alias_directory2.php (Inside a **different** folder outside the doc root)
```

If alias_directory2.php needs both webroot.php and alias_directory.php, This does not work.
(Remember alias_directory.php and alias_directory2.php are not in the same locations)

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/webroot.php'; //(ok)
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/alias_directory.php'; //(not ok)
```

This does not work because alias_directory.php is not in the doc root.

Similarly

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/webroot.php'; //(ok)
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/alias_directory.php'; //(not ok)
```

The problem here is that `dirname(__FILE__)` will return the path for alias_directory2.php not alias_directory.php.

This works:

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/webroot.php'; //(ok)
require_once '/full/path/to/directory/alias_directory.php'; //(ok)
```

But is very nasty and is a maintenance nightmare if I decide to move my library to another location.

How do I solve this problem, is seems that I need a way to resolve an Alias folder properly.

Comment: why **everyone** tend to use `dirname(__FILE__)` in the file access context, no matter if it suitable or not? Looks like everyone take this another way to write a **relative path** as a magic spell to solve any filesystem problem

Comment: No <Directory> nor Alias can affect filesystem calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will not be able to resolve the location of your alias_directory.php file. You will need to supply the location of the alias_directory.php file yourself. Either as an absolute path, or relative to alias_directory2.php or the DOCUMENT_ROOT

Example:

```
If your file locations look something like this:
/var/www/webroot.php
/var/otherdir1/alias_directory.php
/var/otherdir2/alias_directory2.php

From alias_directory2.php you can now include alias_directory.php by either:
require_once('/var/otherdir1/alias_directory.php');
or
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../otherdir1/alias_directory.php');
or
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../otherdir1/alias_directory.php');
```

To use relative paths, alias_directory.php should be located somewhere close to alias_directory2.php or DOCUMENT_ROOT

Another solution would be to add the folders in question to the include_path, and use require_once('alias_directory.php'); without path specification.

Comment: what's the use of `dirname(__FILE__)` here? what if it will be called from  `/var/www/themes/cyan/template.php`?

Comment: As I understood the question, alias_directory.php was to be included from alias_directory2.php.

If the two files are known to be close to each other (as in sibling directories),
    dirname(__FILE__)
will provide the closest starting point for a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname` twice. Once to get the directory of the current file, again to get the parent of that directory, then step back down into the other directory;

```
require_once dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ) . '/other_dir/alias_directory.php';
```